# Derivative of an integral problem.

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

According to Leibnitz rule we have, 
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{g(x)}^{h(x)}\ f(x) \  dx=  f(h(x)).h'(x) - f(g(x)).g'(x)$$

Now we have a function,
$$f(x) = \int_0^x ( f(t) - 1 ) cos(t) dt$$

Applying Leibnitz formula to it we get,
$$f'(x) = ( f(x) - 1 ) cos(x)$$

Now, f(x) = e<sup>sin(x)</sup> + 1 , satisfies the second equation but it does not satisfy the first one. 
Where am I wrong

Comment: What do you mean when you say that it doesn't satisfy the first equation? Do you mean that replacing $f(x) = e^{\sin(x)}+1$ in the second displayed formula leads to a non-correct equality?

Comment: The first equation implies $f(0)=0$. You must add this condition to avoid "false" solutions.

Comment: Ok I have cleared my confusions. More than one curve may have the same differential equation.

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$\int_0^x(e^{\sin(t)}+1-1)\cos(t)\,dt=\int_0^xe^{\sin(t)}\cos(t)\,dt=e^{\sin(t)}\bigg|_{0}^x=e^{\sin(t)}+1=e^{\sin(t)}-1+2.$$
Why this happens is just because, when you differentiate both sides of the equation, you lose alone standing constants. In other words: If 
$$f'(x)=g'(x)$$
then $$f(x)=g(x)+c$$
for some constant to be determined.

Comment: If there is only one solution to the equation and we differentiate the equation to solve it, we will get extra unwanted solutions that do not satisfy the original equation?

Comment: Ok i have understood it now.